# C# - Connect to remote SQL Server securely?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know it's easy to connect to a SQL Server database however I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do it remotely and on the same time.. with a secure way .

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = this.sqlcon();

SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("use " + database_telecaster.ToString() + " SELECT Top 1  sid from dbo.Item order by sid desc", sqlConnection);

sqlConnection.Open();
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader reader = insertCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    MaxSid = (reader.GetInt64(0) + 100).ToString();
}
reader.Close();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

SQL Server con function :

```
public SqlConnection sqlcon()
{
    var doc = new XPathDocument(Application.StartupPath + "/DBConn.xml");
    var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

    var serverName = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/servername");

    var username = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/username");
    var password = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/password");
    var database = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//appsettings/database");

    object[] objArray = new object[] {
            serverName , database, username , password 
    };

    return new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets = True", objArray));
}
```

Assuming that the SQL Server is on a  Windows VPS installed and I'm going to give my software to different people and I want them all to access that SQL server... how I can do that without opening the ports of the SQL Server ? Because as far as I know opening the ports will lead to getting hacked since all people will be able to connect remotely to that server .

Comment: If you're constructing your connection from pieces of information, I'd recommend you use the [**`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of rolling your own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This questions reminds me of me when I was getting started...

Whatever you do, do not connect to the database directly, because to connect directly you would have to store the database connection strings (and passwords) within your application... you could obfuscate it, make it as obscure as you like, it wont make a difference... You'll essentially hand over the keys to the castle.

Instead, you need to start learning how to create an API, that authenticates the client and connects to the data layer on the clients behalf, performs the operations requested and then returns the result.

Personally, I would use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), it's the right tool for the job. There is a slight learning curve to it but just stick with it and you'll have it figured out in a few days. Start off with these [PluralSight videos](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=jon-flanders&name=aspnetwebapi-m1-introduction&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspnetwebapi), they're an excellent resource which is completely free thanks to Microsoft, and they'll certainly keep you busy!

Comment: So if I understood right ,It will be always unsecure to do such a thing , instead I should create an ASP.NET C# website and make a function that my Winforms connects to and get values returned ?
always if I got you , the SQL information's should be stored on the website instead of the application , correct ?

Comment: That's correct, the reason is because nobody can see your server side code, so essentially what you're doing is you're hiding your database behind a web service, and you expose certain urls which your application utilizes to get the data it needs

Comment: Thanks for the useful links :) One more question if you don't mind , now since my urls will be exposed by decompiling or other methods , everyone could access that page and get the returned values ?
making a login system to allow only people that I want them to use the application (server side) should do the job , right ?

Comment: Your URLs will be exposed without even having to decompile :), download this tool called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It's a life saver as you will see exactly what your application is sending to your website, and what your website is returning. And yes, if you don't implement a login system, anyone with the technical know how will be able to see your endpoints with ease. You need to authenticate your users and filter any request that is coming from an anonymous source. (Meaning any user that has not authenticated them selves will not be granted permission to access your data)

Comment: was always a fan of Telerik products but never heard of that one :) well thank you mate , you gave me a great help to improve most of my programs that use SQL connections and should connect remotely :)

Comment: I know this is a little bit old but I have a question regarding this. If I'm building an application in Intranet (local network), will your answer remain valid? or putting the password inside application wouldn't make much of a difference as no one except the people who are supposed to use the application will be using it?

Comment: @Dablackninja it means the password will be travelling in plaintext within the LAN. Whether that is acceptable from a security standpoint depends on your threat model; e.g. is it possible that attackers may be sniffing LAN traffic?

Comment: Can this be done with a generic PHP page? Meaning, if I were to create a PHP page _WITHOUT_ using ASP.NET, would it still return the correct values?